# Is possible to use Same Provisioning with Multiple IOS Devices?

Tags: ios

I found on internet and it seems that it is possible.
The information told that I have to register all devices before I set up
provisioning Profile, is it right?

I wonder that is it possible to register more devices after I set up provisioning profile?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can modify the provisioning profile at any time, but you will have to download and install the new one if you are re-building your app on a device that was just added.

Also, the same iOS device can be registered on multiple developer accounts and tied to multiple provisioning profiles.

Hope this helps!